# How can I use TCPDump on Unix to view messages sent to a specific multicast address?

Tags: networking, multicast, tcpdump

I'm trying to view traffic transmitted to a specific multicast address on a network in order to analyze a protocol we're using.

I don't have Wireshark available on the setup (unfortunately).  TCPDump is available though.  So, can anyone show me a command have TCPDump filter to only view messages transmitted to a secific multicast group address?

Comment: Anyone want to leave a comment for the close vote? I think it's a pretty valid question.

Comment: I voted to close as off-topic. This isn't a programming problem. I'm certain you'll get better answers over at superuser.com

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I believe this should be enough for a specific group:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -vv host 239.255.255.250
```

All multicast traffic:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -vv net 224.0.0.0/4
```

Comment: This is only true for IPv4.

Comment: `tcpdump -v multicast and not broadcast`